# Antlr4: how to avoid excessive semantic predicates?

Tags: java, antlr4

Here is the beginning of my lexer rules:

```
F_TEXT_START
    : {! matchingFText}? 'f"' {matchingFText = true;}
    ;

F_TEXT_PH_ESCAPE
    : {matchingFText && ! matchingFTextPh}? '{=/'
    ;

F_TEXT_PH_START
    : {matchingFText && ! matchingFTextPh}? '{=' {matchingFTextPh = true;}
    ;

F_TEXT_PH_END
    : {matchingFText && matchingFTextPh}? '}' {matchingFTextPh = false;}
    ;

F_TEXT_CHAR
    : {matchingFText && ! matchingFTextPh}? (~('"' | '{')+ | '""' | '{' ~'=')
    ;

F_TEXT_END
    : {matchingFText && ! matchingFTextPh}? '"' {matchingFText = false;}
    ;


IF
    : {! matchingFText || matchingFTextPh}? 'if'
    ;

ELIF
    : {! matchingFText || matchingFTextPh}? 'elif'
    ;

// Lots of other keywords

fragment LETTER
    : ('A' .. 'Z' | 'a' .. 'z' | '_')
    ;
    
VARIABLE
    : {! matchingFText || matchingFTextPh}? LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*
    ;
```

What I am doing is putting my formatted text not just like a normal text token but with a f before, but I add it to my parse tree, to be able to tell if there are errors while parsing (with just `parser.start()`). So a formatted text starts with `f"`, finishes with a `"`, any `"` must be replaced by `""`, and can contain placeholders starting with `{=` and finishing with `}` but if you want to actually write `{=`, you'll have to replace it by `{=/`.
The problem is that in a normal formatted text content (not placeholder), the lexer started to mach not only `F_TEXT_CHAR` but other lexer rules too, like variables. What I did seems pretty dumb, I just put semantic predicates for every other rule to avoid them to be matched in a formatted text's content (but still in a placeholder).

Isn't there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a lexical mode for this. To use lexical modes, you'll have to define separate lexer- and parser grammars. Here's a quick demo:

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

F_TEXT_START
 : 'f"' -> pushMode(F_TEXT)
 ;

VARIABLE
 : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*
 ;

F_TEXT_PH_ESCAPE
 : '{=/'
 ;

F_TEXT_PH_END
 : '}' -> popMode
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;

fragment LETTER
 : [a-zA-Z_]
 ;

fragment DIGIT
 : [0-9]
 ;

mode F_TEXT;

  F_TEXT_CHAR
   : ~["{]+ | '""' | '{' ~'='
   ;

  F_TEXT_PH_START
    : '{=' -> pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE)
    ;

  F_TEXT_END
   : '"' -> popMode
   ;
```

Use the lexer in your parser like this:

```
parser grammar TestParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=TestLexer;
}

// ...
```

If you now tokenise the input `f"mu {=mu}" mu`, you'd get the following tokens:

```
F_TEXT_START              `f"`
F_TEXT_CHAR               `mu `
F_TEXT_PH_START           `{=`
VARIABLE                  `mu`
F_TEXT_PH_END             `}`
F_TEXT_END                `"`
VARIABLE                  `mu`
```

Comment: Thank you for this ! But I don't understand: why didn't you put `F_TEXT_PH_START` in the `F_TEXT` mode ? By the way, thanks for your GitHub repo "mu", it helped a lot !

Comment: I thought `F_TEXT_PH_START` could only occur inside a formatted string. If that is not the case, adjust my example grammar accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it does ! Also, it could merge into `F_TEXT_CHAR` like this:  `F_TEXT_CHAR: ~["{]+ | '""' | '{' ~'=' | '{=/';`

Comment: Also, I'm already using `{` and `}` in my default grammar (but it cannot be in `expression`, what I'm asking for in the parser for a placeholder. What would be the semantic predicate for it ?

Comment: I found the semantic preticate while reading antlr's code: `_modeStack.contains(1)`

Comment: Good to hear you found the solution @Bananasmoothii